# tkinter window isn't closing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a save dialog to use with my pygame file, however, after the save dialog is shutdown, the small blank tk window isn't shutting down.

Here is my code

```
root = Tk()
def save():
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title="Save",defaultextension=".jpg")
    return filename

root.destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you call `save`?

Comment: You never call `save`, and you call `mainloop` after destroying the window... If you need debugging help, you have to post a [mcve].

Comment: you can't do `root.destroy()` before `root.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of reasons why this is happening. Use the following in whichever function, you want to close EVERYTHING (from your question, I'm guessing that you want to do that) in your program:

```
sys.exit()   #if this doesn't work, "import sys" first
```

Let me know if this also, doesn't work (it should).